# How can I load a module from inside a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-modules

I'm trying to get a script running.  Essentially I need to load some modules and then execute a python script.  So something like this...

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
module use /PATH/TO/MODULEFILE
module load MY_MODULE

python my_script.py
```

The problem that I get is that every time I try to execute the script I get this error - "module: command not found".  I don't understand how to change the script to fix this.  I am able to run the module command from the shell.  I also ran "whereis -b module" and I just got "module:".

What do I need to do to get this module loaded from inside the script?  Thanks

Comment: Load the modules inside the the python script `my_script.py`, not inside the bash script. PS: You don't need the bash script if you put `#! /usr/bin/python` at the top of you python script.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the `module` command from your python script by sourcing the `python.py` initialization script provided in the `init` directory of the Modules installation.

Following piece of python code defines `module` function, then enables a modulepath and load a modulefile:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
exec(open('/PATH/TO/MODULES/init/python.py').read())
module('use', '/PATH/TO/MODULEFILE')
module('load', 'MY_MODULE')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable the `module` within your bash script, it could be as simple as using a different command to run the script. For me, running a script `script.sh` as `. script.sh` or as `./script.sh` will correctly load the module, but running it as `sh script.sh` will lead to the error you described above.